# flutter http get request with parameters

Tags: flutter, http, get

I want to send a GET http request with parameters, my problem is that when I add the parameters in the request URL manually it works fine, but when I pass them as parameters it returns an exception without any explanation and somehow the execution stops after Uri.https

here is the code that I want to achieve

```dart
  Future<List<LawFirm>> getLawFirms () async {
    Map<String, dynamic> parameters = {
      'total': true
    };
    final uri =
    Uri.http('www.vision.thefuturevision.com:5000',
        '/api/law-firm', parameters);
    final response = await http.get(uri);
    var dynamicResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
    totaLawFirms = await dynamicResponse['total'];
    var lawFirms = await dynamicResponse['data'];
    List<LawFirm> list = List<LawFirm>.from(lawFirms.map((x) => LawFirm.fromJson(x)));
    print(list);
    notifyListeners();
    return list;
  }
```

and here is the manual way which shouldn't be applied

```dart
    final response = await get(Uri.parse('$baseURL/law-firm?total=true'));
```

I have also tried the `dio` library from `pub.dev` but also wasn't helpful.

And finally thanks in advance to everyone

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> parameters = {
  'total': true
};

var uri = Uri(
  scheme: 'http',
  host: 'www.vision.thefuturevision.com:5000',
  path: '/law-firm',
  queryParameters: parameters,
);

final response = await http.get(uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

 final response =
          await http.get(Uri.parse("${Constants.baseUrl}endpoint/param1/param2"));
```

Just modify your GET request like this.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


callAPI() async {
  String login = "sunrule";
  String pwd = "api";
  Uri url = Uri.parse(
      "http://vijayhomeservices.in/app/api/index.php?apicall=login&login=$login&password=$pwd");
  final response = await http.get(url);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final body = json.decode(response.body);
    print(body.toString());
  } else {
    throw Exception("Server Error !");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Query parameters don't support `bool` type. Use `String` instead: 'true'.

> A value in the map must be either a string, or an Iterable of strings, where the latter corresponds to multiple values for the same key.

```
Map<String, dynamic> parameters = {'total': 'true'};
final uri = Uri.http(
    'www.vision.thefuturevision.com:5000', '/api/law-firm', parameters);
print(uri); // http://www.vision.thefuturevision.com:5000/api/law-firm?total=true
```

See [Uri constructor](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/Uri/Uri.html) for details.

Comment: I knew this point and tried it but didn't solve the problem

Comment: In the question it was the problem, so you are facing an another issue then.

Answer (score 0):

## I had the same problem, hope this helps someone.

```
fetchLawfirms(param1, param2) async{
    var params = {'param1': param1, 'param2': param2};
    var url = Uri.parse('https://www.vision.thefuturevision.com:5000/api/law-firm/');

    url = Uri.https(url.authority, url.path, params);

    http.Response response = await http.get(url, headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Authorization': 'Token your_token_string'
    });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      ///data successfully
      var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
    }
}
```